# Gunicorn intermittently returning HTTP502

Tags: gateway, gunicorn

I'm running gunicorn 19.5.0 with 3 workers and a 30 second timeout on a single Xeon core. Gunicorn is sitting between nginx and postgres. Ngix is on the same server as gunicorn (the webserver), postgres is on a separate database server only accessible on 10.x.x.x.

I get intermittent HTTP502s (bad gateway). The site will go down for anywhere up to a few minutes before coming up again.

I looked at my gunicorn logs, there are lines like this every 5 minutes:

```
[2016-07-04 11:49:24 +0200] [1502] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:2599)
[2016-07-04 11:49:25 +0200] [2613] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2613
```

Searching this error leads me to believe that this is caused by the application server timing out. But my timeout setting is 30s, which is *waaay* longer than I want my pages to load!

I'm the only one using this server though at the moment - it is not getting taxed by lots of http requests. As such, I can't think of a reason why it would timeout - the hardware seems sufficient for the purpose (and I have free RAM, I checked). The server is on a VM - should I be getting in touch with the VPS provider to ask for an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Looked at my uptime monitoring service and response time had been steadily increasing all morning. About 5 minutes after posting the question, I lost the database server and the VPS provider can't bring it back up either. So I guess these problems were all their fault, and I'm waiting on a solution (and explanation) from them.